Lambda @Edge/S3 bucket permissions
I got a Cloudfront distribution which has a Lambda Edge associated to it (Origin response).
The origin for the dist is an S3 bucket.
When hitting the dist path which should trigger the lambda, i get a 503 error:

The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner

My Lambda IAM policy:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:TagResource"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:{ACCOUNT_ID}:log-group:/aws/lambda/{LAMBDA_NAME}*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:GetFunction",
            "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "lambda:EnableReplication*",
            "lambda:DisableReplication*",
            "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}

My S3 bucket policy:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowSignedURLsOrCookies",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET}/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::{ACCOUNT_ID}:distribution/{DIST_ID}"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowOAI",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity{OAI_ID}"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET}/*"
    }
]
}

Am I missing something related to these permissions?
Btw, i'm using the serverless framework (version 4.2.1) for deployment.
